# How to implement Form Projection in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been trying to implement form projection in Angular in accordance with the talk given by Kara Erickson at Angular Connect in 2017, but so far without success.
[link to talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8)

Unfortunately, the only code available appears in the slides and is incomplete so working it out is difficult.
This is what I have attempted but it is throwing errors: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-projection-3

The idea of form projection is that you have some wrapper component whose template contains a `<form>` element and into which you *project* the form contents (the example in the talk is of a form stepper):

```
<!-- FormStepper -->
<form>
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</form>

<!-- containing template, e.g. AppComponent -->
<form-stepper>
   <div ngModelGroup="address">
      <input name="street" ngModel/>
      <input name="city" ngModel/>
   </div>
</form-stepper>
```

A naive implementation such as this results in errors because the ngModelGroup directive expects to be within a form but cannot find the form directive (The ControlContainer class) because of the component boundary.

According to Kara, the solution is to provide the ControlContainer class from the FormStepperComponent's providers. Using a @ViewChild() decorator query, you grab the form directive from the component's view and store it in an instance property, e.g. `form`.

```
  // within FormStepper
  @ViewChild(NgForm) form: NgForm;
```

Then within the providers array, you configure a provider for ControlContainer using useFactory so that when it is requested, it returns the form instance:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useFactory: component => {
        return component.form;
      },
      deps: [FormStepperComponent]
    }
  ],
```

Directives within the FormStepperComponent's content children should be able to inject services provided in the provider's array. This should allow ngModelGroup to get the reference to the form that it needs.

The problem is that the factory function runs before the view is initialised, therefore component.form is undefined at this point.

I have also created this demo which demonstrates content projection and the order in which the view is initialised, the content is initialised, and the factory runs.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-projection-experiment

You can see in the console that the factory provider runs before the view is initialised and so when the directive tries to inject the form it just gets `undefined`.

It looks like what is suggested in this talk isn't even possible?

Comment: Yeah she mentioned this issue and also she added templeteOutlet there. May be you check if that solve

Comment: I experimented with that. It seems like it might be the solution but until I get it working I can't be sure.

Comment: And I've updated the question to take account of templateOutlet. It doesn't seem to make any difference. It's not clear to me why it's even supposed to.

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form :) we built it at work and open sourced it, I think it's what you're looking for

Answer (score 6):

The reason your factory doesn't have the `NgForm` view child defined is that the NgForm `ViewChild` query will query **after** change detection runs **by default**. You need to update the NgForm `ViewChild` query to run **before** change detection runs. This will make sure that the `form` property is defined when your factory runs. You can do this by adding the property `static` to the query and setting it to true, i.e.,

```
@ViewChild(NgForm, { static: true }) form: NgForm;
```

Docs on ViewChild go more in depth on this option: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

I believe when this talk was given, Angular's ViewChild would query before change detection runs by default. Angular has since been updated to query after change detection runs by default. It's too bad they didn't provide code examples for this talk and keep it updated with latest Angular.

I forked your example to make it work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-projection-experiment-uxzdee

Comment: Unfortunately, you forked the wrong example! That was the one I created to demonstrate form projection. The problem is the order of the instantiation of content children and view children rather than change detection, so I'm not sure about your explanation. You could be right, but it's hard to say without a working example. I tried adding the `static:true` property to my example, but I still get errors. Thanks for taking the time to answer all the same.

Comment: I just forked the other example you provided here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-projection-3-4ypybx. I added the static true property and I am not seeing any errors in the console. It seems to work. Is there something else you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, that seems to work now. Possibly Stackblitz was acting up when I tried to run earlier. I have awarded the points as promised.